# Selenium: I want to choose which browser to use with invocation in Command Prompt

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, python-unittest

Currently, I have a .ini file called *testcase.ini* which looks something like this:

```
[TEST]
DRIVER_PATH = C:\Python\
BROWSER = CHROME
; BROWSER = EDGE
; BROWSER = FIREFOX
CHROME_PATH = C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
; EDGE_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
; FIREFOX_PATH = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

To run my automated tests, I open a command prompt in my Test Plan folder and enter a command like this:

```
python TestPlan_LoginTest.py
```

Instead of going in to the testcase config file and commenting out which browsers I don't wish to use when running my automated tests, I'd like to be able to choose the browser when I invoke the test in the command prompt, i.e. something like this:

```
python TestPlan_LoginTest.py Firefox
```

or

```
python TestPlan_LoginTest.py Edge
```

If I don't include a browser in the invocation, it defaults to Chrome.

Is this possible with unittest?  What changes would I need to make and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `pytest` plugin called [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), you can set the browser from the command-line. (It defaults to "chrome" if not specified.) Example:

```sh
pytest test_demo_site.py --edge

pytest my_first_test.py --firefox
```

Or if you prefer to use your own framework, you can find the necessary code for setting `pytest` command-line options here in SeleniumBase: [pytest_plugin.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/pytest_plugin.py)

That link shows you about using `pytest_addoption(parser):` as well as code such as:

```py
    parser.addoption(
        "--edge",
        action="store_true",
        dest="use_edge",
        default=False""",
    )
```

which lets you customize command-line options for use in tests.

Comment: I'm using unittest.  Is this still applicable?

Comment: Yes, because SeleniumBase tests inherit ``unittest.TestCase`` while running with ``pytest``.

Comment: After adding this plugin, will I invoke python or pytest in the command prompt to run my tests (see original examples above for clarification)?

Comment: Use ``pytest``. Running ``pytest -h`` will give you list of all available ``pytest`` command-line options.